# How to understand 'in" in the sentence?

Tags: adverbs

The original sentence:

> If the water was moving with the wave, the ocean and everything on it
>   would be racing **in** to the shore with obviously catastrophic
>   results.

Two questions:

1. I like to confirm that this is a complex sentence in a subjunctive mood for both the dependent and independent clauses, although it is not typical to use a continous tense in subjunctive moods.
2. How to understand the adverb "**in**" after "**racing**"? Is it fine to use "...**racing to the shore**..." or "...**racing into the shore**..."?

Comment: Not sure about your first question but for your second, the answer is yes. "In to the shore" is the same as "into the shore". Basically the same as "racing to the shore" as well, although that version doesnt specify the direction (but its obvious that the water travels "in" to the shore and not "out" to it)

Comment: *Into* does ***not*** always mean the same thing as *in to*, and the use of *racing in to* gives a different shade of meaning than *racing to*. All variations are grammatical, but the meaning will change (even if only subtly). Also note that *racing **into** the shore*, specifically, is somewhat nonsensical (a shore is not typically something that encloses something else), whereas *racing in to the shore* makes perfect sense.

Comment: @JasonBassford, thanks for sharing.

Comment: As for the rest of the question, it is not subjunctive because English does not have a subjunctive mood. It has several irrealis and hypothetical constructions that are often called "subjunctive", but the term is used for all sorts of things, including modal auxiliaries. Better to just ignore it, like split infinitives.